# Getting values of EditTexts from multiple Layouts in Android not working?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Not asked a question in a while so it's been long overdue!

I am creating an app where job items can be created onClick, with each new row containing a Description(EditText), a Price(EditText) and a button to delete the current row, but I am having trouble when getting the values from the EditText fields when there is more than one row - it just returns the values of the newest row.

Aside from the 'Job List Container', the views are created dynamically so pardon the lack of XML, but the structure of what I am trying to achieve is as follows, where clicking the Add button adds a row (this can be multiple rows) and clicking the submit button takes all of the Description and Price values and processes them (adds the prices and adds the job to the DB):

[image]

...and this is the code I've written for it called from the addNewJobRow onClick listener (all together for simplicity):

```
private void addJobItem() {

    //Create a new row container
    final LinearLayout jobRowContainer = new LinearLayout(this);

    //Create a new EditText for the Description
    final EditText description = new EditText(this);
    description.setHint("Description...");
    description.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            1.0f
    ));

    //Create an EditText for the Price
    final EditText price = new EditText(this);
    price.setHint("00.00");

    //Create a new button to delete the row
    Button delete = new Button(this);
    delete.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    delete.setText("X");

    //Add Description, Price and Delete to the row container
    jobRowContainer.addView(description);
    jobRowContainer.addView(price);
    jobRowContainer.addView(delete);

    //Add the Row Container to the Jobs List Container
    ll_jobListContainer.addView(jobRowContainer);

    //Get the values of the Description and Price, for each row
    btn_JobSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            for (int i = 0; i < ll_jobListContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < jobRowContainer.getChildCount(); j++) {

                    if (jobRowContainer.getChildAt(i) instanceof EditText){
                        String descriptionString = description.getText().toString();
                        String priceString = price.getText().toString();

                        System.out.println("z! " + descriptionString + " @ " + priceString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I have tried a couple of iterations of this with and without the nested `FOR` loops and with and without the use of `instanceof`, but all it does is print out the newest row.

So, if I have multiple job rows, how can I get all of the values as required?

Thanks for your time and all that nice stuff xxx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic problem is that you're using only the last instance of `description` and `price` instead of each rows instance.  (This may be what Dmitry is saying as well).  To fix it, you need to get the input for each row.  Here's one way.

Set an ID for `description` & `price`.  (You can't just use '1' or '2', it needs to be a resource type ID so it is guaranteed to be unique).  I made a dummy layout file of a row & assigned IDs in that to the 2 `EditText`s.  There may be a better way to do it.  So anyway, add these 2 lines in your declarations

`descripton.setId(R.id.description);` and `price.setId(R.id.price);`

Now this is your onClick()

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ll_jobListContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
        LinearLayout currentRow = (LinearLayout)ll_jobListContainer.getChildAt(i);
        EditText editText = (EditText)currentRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
        String descriptionString = editText.getText().toString();

        editText = (EditText)currentRow.findViewById(R.id.price);
        String priceString = editText.getText().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "z! " + descriptionString + " @ " + priceString);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  I didn't want to change this answer since it had already been accepted so I've put a more concise solution in another answer.

Comment: Thanks very much Garry99, that worked a treat with all fields across multiple rows accounted for. Cheers dude!

Comment: Glad to have helped.  I just noticed I had 'description' in one place & 'desc' in another.  Fixed it.  Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the extended answer, I have done something similar to this as I needed a layout to be able to assign the resourceID's for the description and price, but I have just left them as dummy items. Pardon my ignorance, but as the first way works fine, what does this addition achieve?

Comment: Functionally, they're the same.  This way just uses less code.

Answer (score 1):

Of cause, your last setOnClickListener takes strings

> String descriptionString = description.getText().toString();
>
> String priceString = price.getText().toString();

Where description and price - is fields in the function (last edittexts).
The good way to do that is to use RecyclerView/ListView, in "onTextChangeListner" of ViewHolder save new text to model of this object and print all text from your models, not directly from views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but aside from the ListView, they are two new things for me. I've looked at the docs for the ViewHolder, can it hold info for more that one row? Any chance of a cheeky request of elaborating on it please?

Comment: ViewHolder can hold any layout. You can create your item as 10-rows LinearLayout.
1)When you have repetitive items, it's better to put them in ListView/RecyclerView for it vill be easier to manage them
2)When your items contains data, it's better to have a model of that data in your presenter for a various reasons - to not lose data in case of elements becoming more that screen can hold, to properly restore state when activity is recreated and so on.

Answer (score 0):

I normally try to answer only question that was asked rather than change code that's not necessary.  However, in this case, since I had created a dummy layout just to get Resource IDs, I wonder if that layout file could be put to use.  I had started to change my answer but original one was accepted before I could make the changes.  I've put a different version of the solution here.  I didn't want to modify an answer that had already been accepted.

```
private void addJobItem() {
    //Create a new row container
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    LinearLayout jobRowContainer = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);

    //Add the Row Container to the Jobs List Container
    ll_jobListContainer.addView(jobRowContainer);

    //Get the values of the Description and Price, for each row
    btn_JobSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ll_jobListContainer.getChildCount(); i++) {
                LinearLayout currentRow = (LinearLayout)ll_jobListContainer.getChildAt(i);
                EditText editText = (EditText)currentRow.findViewById(R.id.description);
                String descriptionString = editText.getText().toString();

                editText = (EditText)currentRow.findViewById(R.id.price);
                String priceString = editText.getText().toString();
                Log.d(TAG, "z! " + descriptionString + " @ " + priceString);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

row_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/single_row">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Description..."
        android:id="@+id/description"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="00.00"
        android:id="@+id/price"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="X"
        android:id="@+id/clear_button"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```